# Distributor_Admin Changing Linked Server "Data Access" Property to False

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, linked-server

Why is the system changing the "Data Access" property on my linked server?  How can I change that?

See [SQL Server linked server's DATA ACCESS property changes to false](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/327492/16641).  I have the same problem as that poster, but my question goes one step further. By running a SQL Audit similar to the answer, I found that "distributor_admin" is changing the "Data Access" property on one specific linked server to false at a seeming random time at night.  Why is the system changing the "Data Access" property on my linked server?

What have I done?

1. Created a scheduled job to correct the setting.  Scheduled to run every 15 minutes.

```
DECLARE @ServerName sysname

select @ServerName = s.name from sys.servers s
where s.name in ('Server1','Server2','Server3')
and s.is_data_access_enabled = 0

IF @ServerName is not null BEGIN
    Print 'Correcting Data Access for ' + @serverName
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=@ServerName, @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
END
```

2. Created a SQL Audit and specification to track changes to the property:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT [LinkedServer]
TO FILE 
(   FILEPATH = N'D:\File\Path\'
    ,MAXSIZE = 0 MB
    ,MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 2147483647
    ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
) WITH (QUEUE_DELAY = 1000, ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE)
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [LinkedServer] WITH (STATE = ON)
GO

CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [LinkedServerMaster]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [LinkedServer]
ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[sys].[sp_addserver] BY [dbo]),
ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[sys].[sp_setnetname] BY [dbo]),
ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[sys].[sp_addlinkedsrvlogin] BY [dbo]),
ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[sys].[sp_dropserver] BY [dbo]),
ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[sys].[sp_addlinkedserver] BY [dbo]),
ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[sys].[sp_droplinkedsrvlogin] BY [dbo]),
ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[sys].[sp_serveroption] BY [dbo])
WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

This is a snippet of what the audit shows:

```
Date        12/11/2023 10:38:58 PM
Log     Audit Collection (LinkedServer)

Event Time  22:38:58.2683130
Server Instance Name    ReplicationServerName
Action ID       EXECUTE
Class Type      STORED PROCEDURE
Sequence Number 1
Succeeded       True
...
Session Server Principal Name   distributor_admin
Server Principal Name   sa
...
Object Name sp_serveroption
Statement       exec @retcode = sp_serveroption @servername, 'data access','false'
Additional Information  <tsql_stack><frame nest_level = '4' database_name = 'mssqlsystemresource' schema_name = 'sys' object_name = 'sp_MSset_repl_serveroptions'/></tsql_stack>
...
Affected Rows   0
Response Rows   0
...
```

Comment: Are you using replication?

Comment: Yes.  The server where this is happening is a distributor and the linked servers that are being affected are subscribers and or publishers.

Comment: Do you commonly script out and drop and / or create new Publications? I believe this is a known side-effect when scripting Publications.

Comment: I'll look for a correlation.  I don't think we create new publications more often than once or twice a month, but that might match the frequency of this breaking.  Thank you @J.D.!